# How to move custom gutenberg block controls from settings to styles tab?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

I'm writing custom Gutenberg blocks for my future projects. I have a few blocks and everyone of these has its own controls that allow change of border attributes, colors etc.

All of these controls are visible under Settings tab as you can see on the screenshot below:
[image: controls are visible under Settings tab]

How can I move these controls to the second, "Styles" tab? Here is the code I use:

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import {
    __experimentalBorderControl as BorderControl,
    __experimentalUnitControl as UnitControl 
} from '@wordpress/components';
import {
    useBlockProps,
    InnerBlocks,
    InspectorControls
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import metadata from '../config/paper-block.json';

registerBlockType(metadata, {
    edit: ({attributes, setAttributes }) => {
        //(... a lot of code here)

        return <div {...blockProps}>
            <InspectorControls key="settings">
                <div className="block-editor-block-card">
                    <fieldset>
                        <UnitControl
                            label={__("Szerokość kartki", "ebl")}
                            value={ attributes.width }
                            onChange={ changeWidth }
                            units={ units }
                        />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div className="block-editor-block-card">
                    <fieldset>
                        <BorderControl
                            label={__("Obwód, krawędź (border)", "ebl")}
                            value={ attributes.border }
                            onChange={ changeBorder }
                            enableAlpha={true}
                        />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </InspectorControls>
            <InnerBlocks />
        </div>
    },

    save: ({attributes}) => {
        //(... a lot of code here)
    }
});
```

Should I do something with  component?

Comment: note that border width is something your block can opt into, enabling WP itself to provide border controls and a UI without you needing to add an attribute/control, and it would put it on the styles tab, it would even have better `block.json` and `theme.json` controls! Something similar might exist for width. If you can do that it will save a lot of effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `group` property of `InspectorControls` to `styles`:

```
<InspectorControls group="styles">
    // etc.
</InspectorControls>
```

The other possible groups are described in [this article](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/03/07/introduction-of-block-inspector-tabs/).